# Php and href - link executing 2 actions

Tags: php, hyperlink, href

I would like that a link in admin page to generate two actions at once.
First one is creating an invoice for an order( which it does today) and secondly put it in a certain status, which we have numbered 1-6.

Here is the code which today create an invoice:

```
echo '<a target="_blank" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href" href="invoice.php?createInvoice&container=ALL&orderId='.$row['id'].'">Create Invoice</a>';
```

What I would like is to make use of this code when I click the link is:

```
?showorder&status=6&id
```

To put it in a status 6.

Is it possible to add it somehow or do I have to do something else?

Comment: you have PHP tagged in your question. if you are using PHP simply link to some type of processing page, and execute the PHP in there to perform your actions. just an FYI you are going down a big rabbit hole here.

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href"
```

Remove this segment because there is no need for you to reload it when you're already hrefing it to your PHP.

In `invoice.php`, redirect it the success page or back to the page using `header()`.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that!
I know we had some problem with the page not reloading as you clicked the link and created the invoice, which sometimes resulted in accidents of creating a second invoice on the same order. Our former IT-consultant I believe solved this by that adding this to opening it in a new window like this perhaps?

/Robin